# Edit order doesn't load products

Tags: magento-1.9, edit-order

I'm trying to edit an order and normally Magento 1.9.0.1 loads all the items in the order and adds them to the new order, in this case it isn't.

I'm trying to figure out how to go about debugging this, I want to find the Magento call to get items and where it's tripping, I have been unsuccessful so far, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any luck? I'm facing the same issue here :)

Comment: Chester, this ended up being because we were using Mageworx Custom Options, there was a bug in their module.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to extends function from the `sales.js` file:

```
var Magesales = new Class.create(AdminOrder,{
    loadArea : function(area, indicator, params){
        //keep the checkbox checked after ajax request. Added separate condition when the user change the shipping method.
        // we want in that case that the billing method not to be reload
        if (area == 'shipping_method,totals,billing_method'){
            this.customdata = 'shipping_method,totals';
        }else{
            this.customdata = true;
        }
        var url = this.loadBaseUrl;
        if (area) {
            area = this.prepareArea(area);
            url += 'block/' + area;
        }
        if (indicator === true) indicator = 'html-body';
        params = this.prepareParams(params);
        params.json = true;
        if (!this.loadingAreas) this.loadingAreas = [];
        if (indicator) {
            this.loadingAreas = area;
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                parameters:params,
                loaderArea: indicator,
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                    this.loadAreaResponseHandler(response);
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }
        else {
            new Ajax.Request(url, {parameters:params,loaderArea: indicator});
        }
        if (typeof productConfigure != 'undefined' && area instanceof Array && area.indexOf('items') != -1) {
            productConfigure.clean('quote_items');
        }
    },
    loadAreaResponseHandler : function (response){
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.message);
        }
        if(response.ajaxExpired && response.ajaxRedirect) {
            setLocation(response.ajaxRedirect);
        }
        if(!this.loadingAreas){
            this.loadingAreas = [];
        }
        if(typeof this.loadingAreas == 'string'){
            this.loadingAreas = [this.loadingAreas];
        }
        if(this.loadingAreas.indexOf('message') == -1) {
            this.loadingAreas.push('message');
        }
        // Add Totals
        if(this.loadingAreas.indexOf('card_validation') != -1) {
            this.loadingAreas.push('totals');
        }
        for(var i=0; i<this.loadingAreas.length; i++){
            var id = this.loadingAreas[i];
            if($(this.getAreaId(id))){
                if ('message' != id || response[id]) {
                    if (this.customdata == true) {
                        this.loadSection(response, id);
                    }else{
                        //getting the ids for shipping methods
                        var getIds = this.customdata.split(',');
                        for (var i=0; i< getIds.length; i++){
                            this.loadSection(response, getIds[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($(this.getAreaId(id)).callback) {
                    this[$(this.getAreaId(id)).callback]();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    loadSection : function(response, id){
        var wrapper = new Element('div');
        wrapper.update(response[[id]] ? response[[id]] : '');
        $(this.getAreaId([id])).update(Prototype.Browser.IE ? wrapper.outerHTML : wrapper);
    }
});
AdminOrder = Magesales;
```

I added a separate condition for area and depends on that I reload the `billing_method`.  I believe their is a better solution for this so I am open for those to see . Thx